# Express anonymous with formal parameters

Tags: functions, functional-style

I'd like to express the function
`F = Function[{#2[[1]] + #1[[2]]/#1[[1]], #2[[2]] + 1/#1[[1]]}]`
using explicit formal parameters.

I've tried `G = Function[{{a, b}, {c, d}},{c + b/a, d + 1/a}]`
but this doesn't seem to work. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory isn't it? Is there some reason you can't do `g[{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}] := {c + b/a, d + 1/a}`?

Comment: I could do something like that (`g[{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}] := {c + b/a, d + 1/a}`), but I want to do it anonymously with explicit parameters.